# Preventing multiple downloads for Java Web Start/JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

We have a Swing application which initiated from the Web application by clicking a link. The link is nothing but a JNLP url. There is a jar file hosted on our four servers under Apache. These are under a load balancer. Even though the same jar is hosted with the same time stamp but more or less every request to the JNLP the jar is gettign downloaded. Generally if there is no change in the jar the java Web start downloads only once and subsequent requests are works without downloading. What else the info it checks to compare with server version and local copy of jar?

Answer (score 1):

Jar is hosted in Apache and by default apache looks at three things (timestamp+size+ETAG)
Since it is hosted in four apache servers the ETAG for each server is different and that is why it downloads whenever the request goes to one of these four servers. The fix is to remove the ETAG by overriding the apache configuration.